# Source for Quiet Tochacha Leining

Tags: rebuke-tochacha, ki-tavo, bechukosai

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (78:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.78.4?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) brings the custom of

> וְכָל מַה שֶׁקּוֹרֵא בְּקוֹל נָמוּךְ, צָרִיךְ שֶׁיְהֵא עַל כָּל
> פָּנִים הַקּוֹל נִשְׁמַע לַצִבּוּר - Anyone who reads [the Tochacha]
> in a low voice must ensure their voice is loud enough to be
> audible to the congregation.

Although I am curious to understand *why* some have this custom, my main question is the source for the statement that we *lein* the Tochacha quietly because [Mishlei 25:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.25.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) writes:

> בְּאֹרֶךְ אַפַּיִם יְפֻתֶּה קָצִין וְלָשׁוֹן רַכָּה
> תִּשְׁבָּר־גָּרֶם׃ - Through forbearance a ruler may be won over; A
> gentle tongue can break bones.

as reading the rebuke softly will have a more powerful effect on listeners.

Comment: Maybe Megillah 31b

Comment: Rabbi Mordechai Kamenetsky writes that we "read the verses of tochacha quietly, so as not to rile up enemies, celestial and otherwise, who may think those calamities a good idea to cast upon the Jewish Nation." - he doesn't bring a source though - https://torah.org/torah-portion/shabbos-5768-netzavim/

Comment: @DoubleAA I recently learned that Gemara and saw mefarshim that indicated that. Can't find them right now though.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Maybe we want the rebuke to have a powerful effect on listeners?

Comment: @JoelK Your point is precisely the source I'm looking for. We do seem to want to have the rebuke effect people in a powerful way, but where do we find a source saying that's the reasoning behind reading quietly?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Yoel Lieberman [quotes](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/7758) the ספר המטעמים saying

> since the curses are words of rebuke, the way for people to accept
> them is to say them softly. What has been said by other commentators
> in regard to reading the portion of the Torah  dealing with the golden
> calf ,  which in some communities also used to be read softly may also
> apply here. The custom was so to  indicate that reading this portion
> of the Torah is somewhat embarrassing and therefore it is not
> something we want to read so much out loud.

Comment: Some websites quote the Sefer Hamatamim page 144 saying "משום 'דברי חכמים בנחת נשמעים', ו'דברי' הוא תוכחה, כדכתיב 'אלה הדברים'" but the one on Hebrewbooks only goes up to 109...https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20709&st=&pgnum=105&hilite=